# Does MSAppProxy work for SharePoint (on-prem) webhooks

Tags: sharepoint

We're currently developing for a SharePoint Server Subscription instance.
We want/need to use SharePoint list webhooks.
These work when I use ngrok as a proxy for my development environment.
When I publish my backend app to our webserver, it is unable to successfully create webhook subscriptions.
This webserver is normally not reachable from outside our company's network, unless the MS app proxy('s URL) (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/app-proxy/application-proxy) is used.
When I run ngrok on that same webserver (and use that url to create a subscription), it is able to create subscriptions.
In the same backend app, webhook subscriptions for users' email accounts are created/used (via Microsoft Graph), and those do work (via the MSAppProxy).
So we have Microsoft Graph that's able to reach our application behind the MSAppProxy and SharePoint that's isn't able to reach our application behind the MSAppProxy.
I've checked the incoming traffic on that webserver and it never receives a request from SharePoint when the MSAppProxy url is being used, so it's like it's being blocked at the MSAppProxy level.